# Software for analyzing lengthy, fixed perspective footage

Tags: windows, video, data-analysis

I have several hours of footage sitting on my hard drive that I need to analyze. Each recording is from a camera that's pointed towards a location and I'm looking for any software that can tell me which time intervals show motion, preferably with adjustable detection sensitivity. There's a couple programs out there that use a webcam to start recording once motion is detected but I'm looking for something that can analyze prerecorded footage.

Windows software preferred.

Thank you.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I should've specified, sorry. Preferably for Windows.